# convert column to row in postgresql database

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, crosstab, postgresql-9.4

My current query is:

```
select rulename,status, count(*)
from triggered_rule_info
group by status, rulename
```

And the result is:

```
rulename    status  count
eorule1      ack    1
eorule1      open   1
eorule1      close  7
eorule2      open   1
eorule2      ack    1
```

But I want the result to be:

```
rulename     ack    open    close
eorule1       1      1       7
eorule2       1      1
```

How can I achieve this? My postgresql version is 9.4.

Comment: Google for "SQL pivot query"

Comment: @Dipalis.: how can an answer for SQL Server that uses many SQL Server specific features be a duplicate for a Postgres question?

Answer (score 1):

For that you can use the `filter` clause:

```
select rulename
       count(*) filter (where status = 'ack') as ack,
       count(*) filter (where status = 'open') as open,
       count(*) filter (where status = 'close') as closed
from triggered_rule_info
group by rulename
order by rulename;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `CASE - WHEN` and `GROUP BY` clauses to get the desired result. You may require to add more `CASE` statements if `status` has more other values.

***Example***:

```
SELECT rulename
     , SUM( CASE status WHEN 'ack' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS "ack"
     , SUM( CASE status WHEN 'open' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS "open"
     , SUM( CASE status WHEN 'close' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS "close"
  FROM triggered_rule_info
 GROUP BY rulename
 ORDER BY rulename
```